# How to stop .Net looking for .config files for my executable

Tags: c#, .net, config

I have a program called **parser.exe** and it uses a config file called **parser.config** (a txt format; I read it with streamreader). For some reasons C# complains and doesn't like this.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration
>   system failed to initialize --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrors

BUT if I created a file called **parser.exe.config**. with just followng content application runs fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Why this is happening and how to suppress this problem without having parser.exe.config  and changing the config name from parser.config to parser.exe.config?

Comment: whats is in parser.config ?

Comment: a config file. plain text. it tells the program what files name to read/use etc.

Comment: but it has all xml nodes? Its not only "Property 1, proeprty 2" but key value etc? <add key="Field" value="xxxx"/>

Comment: @JohnRyann show some code please

Comment: Side note: I've changed title as your question have nothing in particular with C# (except you happen to use C# to write managed code). Feel free to revert/improve.

Comment: Generally when you are trying to fight a platform's convention, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> it uses a config file called parser.config (a txt format; I read it with streamreader)

There's no need for this. .NET already has a perfectly good framework for [application configuration files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx).  Just add an `app.config` file to your project and Visual Studio will automatically create a `parser.exe.config` file when you build.
You can then use the `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` dictionary to read individual configuration items - or use more complex structured for more complex configurations.

To use an external configuration file for a config section, just use the `configSource` attribute in `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings configSource="parser.config" />
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

`parser.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="Test" value="This is a test"/>
</appSettings>
```

> why this is happening?

That's the way the framework was designed - it will look for a {executable name}.config file by default - you can *add* external config files as explained above but there's no way that I know of to have the framework look for a *different* file name by default.

You *could* load a new file into a *separate* configuration object:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"parser.config";
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

But then you have to use that `config` instance to access config settings:

```
Console.WriteLine(config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value);
```

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"]);
```

But that seems like a long way to go to avoid the default config file name.

Comment: yes, this is what I thought. but what if I chose parser.config. how can I make c# to accept that?

Comment: Well you can use external config file for configuration sections.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: this means I still have to have parser.exe.config? my goal is to eliminate the existence of the file.

Comment: +1. @JohnRyann - one approach would be not to use .Net altogether - C++ is perfectly fine for Windows apps too... Just consider ".config" the same as you'd ".exe" or ".dll" - extension reserved by system/framework for particular purpose. Trying to name your own unrelated files with well known extension will only create confusion.

Comment: parser.config is just a text file. all I do is just reading the file with streamreader. why .NET is making a big fuss about it and the app.config is involve ? it is weird. if I changed the file to parser.txt will it complain also?

Comment: Probably not - because then you won't be colliding with the framework's config file mechanism.

Comment: why parser.txt is not colliding , but parser.config is colliding? is it because parser.config has the word "<appname>config" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell .NET to look for your settings in another file, like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="parser.config"></appSettings> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: where should I put the config about? parser.exe.config ? this means I have to have parser.exe.config in the first place. my goal is to make  my program to accept that I am using parser.config without having to have parser.exe.config

Comment: correct - you have to have the .NET app.config (which when "built" gets renamed parser.exe.config in your case.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. my program is working perfectly find IF I have parser.exe.config. My goal is to remove the existence of that file and make c# to accept that I only user parser.config

Comment: No, I understand your question, but I am trying to say that if you HAVE to have your file, that's the way to do it